# Can only access asp.net app on localhost

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm trying to get an asp.net application up on IIS on a Windows Server 2008 machine.  I can hit the app from localhost, no problem.  But I can't access the app using the server's domain name either locally or from another machine on the network.

But here's the odd part.  I can access a normal file on IIS using the domain name, both from a browser running on the server and from a browser running on another machine on the network.  Here's a synopsis ("http" converted to "htp" below because I don't have enough points to have all these links in my message):

From IE on the server itself:
works   htp://localhost/foo.htm
works   htp://localhost/App
works   htp://test.foo.com/foo.htm
dead    htp://test.foo.com/App

From IE on another machine:
works   htp://test.foo.com/foo.htm
dead    htp://test.foo.com/App

And when I say "dead" I mean the request times out.

Any ideas?

Comment: Server configuration questions are more adapted to http://serverfault.com There you could get better support on installing and configuring your web server, network and firewall for the particular operating system you are working with. If you have a programming related question then don't hesitate to post it here.

Comment: Does it time out or go "Page Not Found" error (404)

Comment: It does not result in 404.  It's a timeout on the client side.

Comment: Check Windows Event Log on the server - please post any unusual event messages that result when a client browses to your app.

Comment: I've combed through the log pretty well just now and I don't see any events at all (unusual or otherwise) going into the logs when I browse the app, either through localhost or the domain name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I worked this out.  Basically the app was redirecting to https, but only for remote connections, and IIS was not bound to 443.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer so others can benefit from the (hours? minutes? days ..?) you spent getting to the bottom of this ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your server's domain name is `myServer` and its IP is `192.168.2.1`.

Try `ping`-ing the server from another machine by its domain name. In a `DOS` prompt type:

```
ping myServer
```

Do you get a response?

Try accessing the site on the server using the server's IP address:

```
http://192.168.2.1/foo.htm
```

If its visible by IP but not `ping`able by name then your issue is related to DNS. You need to

- set up IIS so the site is bound to the host name (`Host Name` via the `Edit Bindings ...` option for the site in IIS Manager).
- if you have a DNS server you need to get an admin to put entries in its lookup db for the server.
- if you don't, put an entry in your hosts file for the server.

HTH

Comment: I can do better than ping - I can actually hit htp://test.foo.com/foo.htm and htp://192.168.168.20/foo.htm, from either the server itself or another machine on the network.  I can even hit htp://test.foo.com/foo.htm from completely outside the network.  I just can't hit htp://test.foo.com/App.

Comment: That folder 'App' - have you tried renaming it to something else? I know the reserved folder names mostly start with 'App_' ... (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx) but not sure this would cause any issues. Too busy to test it out just now...

Is the folder configured as a virtual directory? Could the problem be due to permissions-related issues on the server e.g. does the account your ASP process is running under on the server box have access to the folder ?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to configure your iis look this link http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/28/installing-iis-7-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7/